# Can't use QMainWindow after opened a QDialog (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdialog

In my program I have the following problem: After I opened a `QDialog` from `QMainWindow`, I can't use the `QMainWindow`, only if I close the `QDialog` first.
Is there a solution for this?

Thank you,

Mate

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: You probably need a non-[modal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#modal-prop) `QDialog`.

Comment: void MainWindow::on_action_sszes_Mez_rt_k_triggered()
{
    DialogFields fields;
    fields.adatokFogad((ui->listType->currentRow()+1),(ui->listGroup->currentRow()),(ui->tableWidgetField->currentRow()+1),(ui->actionRemi_mod->isChecked()));
    fields.setModal(true);
    fields.exec();
}

I guess the problem is I'm using exec() instead of show(). But When I'm trying to use show(), It just opens my dialog then closes it immediately.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with.  In a comment, it's hard to read, and not necessarily permanent.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the event loop of exec you can use Dialog->show().

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you create your dialog on the stack. That's why you dialog is deleted after `on_action_sszes_Mez_rt_k_triggered()` finished. You must create your dialog on the heap:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QScopedPointer>
...

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QScopedPointer<DialogFields> fields_;
};

...

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    field_.reset(new DialogFields());
}

...

void MainWindow::on_action_sszes_Mez_rt_k_triggered() 
{ 
   fields_->adatokFogad((ui->listType->currentRow()+1),
     (ui->listG‌​roup->currentRow()),‌​
     (ui->tableWidgetFiel‌​d->currentRow()+1),
     (‌​ui->actionRemi_mod->‌​isChecked()));
   fields_->show(); 
}
```